# Alternatives to truffle?

Tags: contract-deployment, migration

I know nothing of solidity and I don't even understand what a dApp is or how to access one, so this question might be silly.

But I have a contract to migrate and it hangs, so I want to try migrating with something else to see if the problem is the contract or truffle, Parity or my private blockchain.

Do you have alternatives that you could list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [Embark](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework) for example, as an alternative for Truffle.

Given that you admit very little knowledge about Solidity, most likely the problem does not have to do with Truffle and it won't be solved by migrating to Embark or something else.

You could post the contract code and the errors you are getting so we can help you figure out what's failing.

Comment: Thank you for the offer but I can't post the contract code.  I don't think the problem is with truffle anymore.  But if I can try deploying with another tool then maybe the combination of error messages will help.

Also, the contract deploys just fine on the --dev network, and it deploys fine on my private blockchain when I add the --geth flag to Parity.  So I doubt the problem is with the contract.  I currently assume that the problem is either a quirk with Parity or with my private blockchain and I have asked Questions to attack the problem from all angles.

Answer (score 1):

Populous is a Python based framework for developing Solidity smart contracts:

http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

[Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) is one of the best frameworks in 2021. They have fast tests, good tutorials and easy integration.

Also a quick google of blockchain developer contracts returns many jobs which list hardhat as a required skill which tells you something about its popularity.